# How to set up proxymesh with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, http-proxy

I have some Scrapy code that I'd like to start using with proxymesh. The [proxymesh documentation](http://proxymesh.com/http-client-examples/) says cryptically:

> For the scrapy crawling framework, you must set the http_proxy
>   environment variable [...] then [activate](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware) the HttpProxyMiddleware.

I understand how to set the `http_proxy` environment variable, but how to "activate the HttpProxyMiddleware" is not totally obvious from the documentation. I *think* I need to add the following to `settings.py` in my Scrapy project:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middleware.ProxyMeshMiddleware': 100,
}
```

But then I presume I also need to add some actual middleware code, presumably in a `middleware.py` file?

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wtrevino/c4ff3918914e4a80b793), so I guess I could just copy and paste that into `middleware.py`, but I'm not sure whether it's accurate. It seems to use different environment variables from what's recommended in the proxymesh documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gist that you are referring to reads ProxyMesh settings from OS environment variables, otherwise it is slightly modified code of basic Scrapy HttpProxyMiddleware and should works well.

You can also look at my very simple implementation of Proxymesh Middleware https://github.com/mizhgun/scrapy-proxymesh that supports proxy rotation (if you have ProxyMesh plan with multiple endpoints) and customisable timeout.

Comment: Thank you! I did also see your library, but I wasn't sure how to get started with it, beyond editing the settings file as described in your README. Is it simply a case of copying the `scproxymesh` directory into my project?

Comment: You can either copy sources to your project or install it using pip `pip install -e git+https://github.com/mizhgun/scrapy-proxymesh@master#egg=scproxymesh`

Comment: UPD: uploaded to PyPI, now can be installed via `pip install scrapy-proxymesh`

Comment: Thanks, will check

Comment: In case anyone is looking for a py3k-compatible version, I have made a fork and published it to Pypi (since the pull request to original repo with py3k support is stale for 2+ years) - https://github.com/kristobaljunta/scrapy-proxymesh-py3